# Is there a crossing-free planar embedding of the 2-skeleton of the 6-simplex?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

A *pseudo-disk arrangement* is a collection of planar bodies whose boundaries are Jordan curves that pairwise intersect at most twice.
I would like to know if given seven points in the plane whether it is possible to find a pseudo-disk arrangement with $\binom 73$ disks, such that for each triple of the seven points there is one disk containing exactly them from the set of seven points.
I'm also interested in what kind of theorems there are to conclude the non-existence of such embeddings.

I've just realized that I don't even know the answer if we replace seven with five.
For five points we can find a *pseudo-ball arrangement* is $3d$; take a tetrahedron with a point inside, and slightly perturb the ten triangles they span.
Can we do more points in $3d$?
In $4d$ any number of points are OK if we aim for triples (just like pairs would be OK in $3d$).

Please note that I've updated the question a couple of times to make the problem more clear, some of the comments and Jeff's answer are for older versions.

Comment: I'm confused by this definition of "cross."  It seems to me that if you have two triangles $ABC$ and $ABD$ whose intersection is exactly equal to the segment $AB$, then those triangles "cross" by the definition given.  No?  [For any four points in the plane, we can find such a configuration.]  **Nevermind!  I missed the disclaimer about "niceness."**

Comment: Do I understand correctly that two convex plane figures don't cross if and only if their boundaries intersect no more than twice?

Comment: If I understood correctly (see previous comment), then the answer is "no", both for five and for seven points: the points must be in a convex position, and then we choose two "crossing triples" and show that the figures containing them must cross. But I think the original version of your question was about not necessarily convex figures?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: (привет, Илья!) Do you mean, for this configuration one can find non-crossing non-convex figures?

Comment: @Ilya: One of the triangles would contain a fourth point, that's not allowed.

Comment: Yes, that's why the points must be in convex position. And then the figure that contains the points 1, 2, 4, crosses the figure that contains 1, 3, 5.

Comment: @Ivan: You understand well that two bodies cross iff their boundaries intersect more than twice, and your argument would work for the version when the bodies are required to be convex, which is what I have erroneously posted first. I want the bodies to be *connected* and not *convex*, sorry for the mistake - the convex version would be easy, just as you've described.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what I've missed.

Comment: Just to check the definition. If we have three vertices of the triangle A,B,C and D and E in the interior in general position and consider the 10 convex hulls. Which of those cross?

Comment: @Gil: I don't think any of them do.

Comment: Can we just say, two (topological) disks $A$, $B$ are non-crossing if the interiors of $A \setminus B$ and of $B \setminus A$ are open disks?

Comment: @Ivan: yes, that would be another equivalent reformulation.

Comment: dear domotorp, so this may be a crossing free embedding?

Comment: @Gil: It is crossing-free, but not the embedding of the 3-uniform hypergraph  I was looking for, as the triangles don't contain exactly three of the five points. (There was a comment by someone saying this replying to you, but it got deleted for some reason.)

Comment: I see, but if we delete from each triangle a very thin neighborhood of a line segment from its boundary to a point that is not suppose to be inside. would this violate the non-crossing?

Comment: @Gil I think it would.

Comment: To explain, here is a slightly different example: Take a triangle A, B, C, with a vertex inside, D. If you take the triangle minus a segment from the midpoint of AB to D, then this set will cross the (slightly thickened version of the) AB segment.

Comment: Wouldn't a positive answer for the $4$-simplex give a planar embedding of the complete graph on $5$ points (draw arcs inside your path-connected pieces).

Comment: @Jeff But how do you  know that the edges won't cross? For example, $K_4$ is not outerplanar, and you can find four disks, one for each of its triples, that are non-crossing and are all inside the convex hull of the four points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is no pseudo-disk arrangement even with $\binom{5}{3}$ pseudo-disks for the 5 point case; I sketch a proof below.

Suppose for contradiction that there is such an arrangement.
Let $a_1,\dots, a_5$ be the points. For each closed Jordan curve $c_{ijk}$ that surrounds $a_i,a_j$ and $a_k$ we define a Jordan arc $d_{lm}$ that connects the remaining two points $a_l$ and $a_m$ in the unbounded region of $c_{ijk}$. We should define the $d$-curves in a way that there are no touchings between them or with the $c$-curves, and also we should make sure that the number of curve incidences in the whole picture is finite.

I claim that a pair of $d$-curves that don't share an endpoint must intersect an even number of times Wlog. consider the curves $d_{12}$ and $d_{45}$. The closed Jordan curves $c_{123}$ and $c_{345}$ together define four regions in the plane, one unbounded, one containing $a_1$ and $a_2$, one containing $a_3$, and one containing $a_4$ and $a_5$. Let $I$ be the union of the three bounded regions. Notice that the boundary of $I$ is made up of two curves, one is an arc of $c_{123}$, while the other is an arc of $c_{345}$.

Since any intersection point $q \in d_{12} \cap d_{45}$ must lie outside $I$, both $d_{12}$ and $d_{45}$ has at least one arc outside $I$. Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^2/I$. In this space, the curves $d_{12}$ and $d_{45}$ become collections of closed Jordan curves that contain the point $p$ that is the picture of $I$ in the contraction. Since one boundary arc of $I$ is only intersected by $d_{12}$ and the other only by $d_{45}$, the curve endigns around $p$ are `separable', i.e., if we label each curve ending by  $a$ for the curve $d_{12}$ and by $b$ for the curve $d_{45}$, then the cyclic order of the labels around $p$ is $a^{2k}b^{2l}$ for some positive integers $k,l$.

Let $g_1,\dots,g_k$ be the closed Jordan curves of $d_{12}/I$ and let $g'_1,\dots,g'_l$ be the closed Jordan curves of $d_{45}/I$. In order to show that $|d_{12} \cap d_{45}|$ is even, it is sufficient to show that $|g_i \cap g'_j|$ is even for any pair $i,j$. We have seen that $g_i$ and $g'_j$ are two closed Jordan curves that touch at the singular point $p$. It follows that they must have an even number of crossings.

The $d$-curves give a planar drawing of the 5-clique, where the curves corresponding to any pair of non-incident edges intersect an even number of times. This contradicts the strong Hanani-Tutte theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a positive answer using connected sets whose boundary is not a Jordan curve.

We want $m={n \choose k}$ connected sets, $S_1, S_2, \ldots , S_m\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.  I'll want to associate each of these sets with a $k$-tuple, so I'll just refer to the $i^\mathrm{th}$ $k$-tuple.

Start with the graphs $G_i$ of $f_i (x) = \sin({1\over x})+ {i\over 2m}$ for $x > 0$ and $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m$.  Each of these graphs has 
the entire interval $I = \{ 0\} \times [{1\over 2}, 1]$ in its set of limit points.  Break $I$ into $n$ subintervals $I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_n$ (ordered
with increasing $y$-values.

Next, line up your $n$ points $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ along the line $x=-1$ (ordered with increasing $y$-values) and from $a_j$ draw ${n-1\choose 2}$ distinct line segments to the interval $I_j$.

Now for a the $i^\mathrm{th}$ $k$-tuple $\{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_k\}$ (wlog), we form the set $S_i$ as the union of $G_i$ with the $k$ segments

- out of $a_1$ corresponding to $2$-tuple $\{a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_k\}$
- $\vdots$
- out of $a_k$ corresponding to $2$-tuple $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{k-1}\}$

The fact that these sets are connected is the standard use of the topologist's sine curve.  They plainly do not intersect.

The same method can be used to embed any countable hypergraph in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Sorry, but when I said nice boundary, I meant no tricks like this.

Comment: Ok.  Probably you could be more clear, since the boundaries here are vertical segments and isolated points, hardly pathological.

Comment: Say, I want each body to be a polygon.

Comment: I've also added a clarification to the problem.

Comment: Ah!  Anyway, I'll leave my answer because it's kind of interesting.

Comment: Sure, though maybe you could add to the beginning that this is for a slightly different version of the problem.

Comment: Good plan: done.